# Consulta por Evento DataGridView

Tags: c#

¿en que evento de un DataGridView debo colocar codigo para que cuando este mismo se encuentre vacio, es decir sin ninguna fila el TextBox1 quede inhabiltado pero cuando tenga una o mas filas al TextBox1 le suceda lo contrario? es decir habilitarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Esta es una comunidad que resuelve dudas especificas, por lo tanto, aquí no hacemos códigos o tareas. Te invito a leer [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta en stackoverflow?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Así que te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código que hayas hecho y de paso, detalla el problema que tengas con el código.

Comment: Investiga todos los eventos que tiene el datagridview, mirando en la ventana de propiedades. Siempre se ayuda a quien investiga y no puede resolver. No sin hacer el intento

Answer (score 0):

Creo que dataGridView no tiene nada para eso, pero podrías hacerlo con un timer que compruebe cada cierto tiempo el contenido del dataGridView.

```
   private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e){

       if(dataGridView[0,1].Value.ToString() == String.Empty){ 

           texBox1.Enabled = false; //si no tiene contenido queda inhabilidato
       }
       else{

           texBox1.Enabled = true; //si tiene contenido queda habilitado
    }
```